# Integration of rational functions by partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

I have the following integral :

$$\int \frac{x^2+2x+3}{x^2-5x+6}~dx$$

Although I tried to solve it by partial fractions, I could not come up with an appropriate answer. My question is more about the technique which I should use here in order to evalue the integral. I understand that the denominator could be expressed as 
$$(x-2)(x-3)$$
But then how to proceed with such a complicated numerator.

Comment: Then $\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+2}dx$  = $\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2+1}d(x+1)= tg^{-1} (x+1)$

Comment: Yeah, this is ok. But I have also an integral where this des not work. My question was more about the technique. I am editing the answer in order to explain better. Thenk you for the fast answers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,
$$
x^2+2x+3=1\cdot (x^2-5x+6)+7x-3.
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{x^2+2x+3}{x^2-5x+6}=1+\frac{7x-3}{x^2-5x+6}.
$$
You know $x^2-5x+6=(x-2)(x-3)$. It is known that there exists $A,B$ such that
$$
\frac{7x-3}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x-3}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{7x-3}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{(A+B)x-(3A+2B)}{x^2-5x+6}.
$$
Thus we get $A=-11$ and $B=18$. Therefore
$$
\int\frac{x^2+2x+3}{x^2-5x+6}dx=x-11\ln|x-2|+18\ln|x-3|+C.
$$

Comment: Perfect answer.